# how to get video link from of live streaming videos using java?

Tags: java, video, video-streaming, download

I want to get exact video link from some streaming video resources like you-tube or metacafe.com, As there is no direct link of video is available. How can I parse the video
link. Also how to use java to download a streaming video from http url to local system?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a library called [HTMLParser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) before. It can read html input and generate HTML nodes. You can then analyze and retrieve the node you like.

Comment: suppose a video is streaming by s specific player designed for a video sharing website how HTMLParser can be used to get the actual url the player is streaming from?